# Previously loaded packages not working

Tags: packages

I'm a complete beginner at Mathematica.

I was trying to learn the basics over the last couple of days. Yesterday I downloaded the GREATER2 package from [here](http://www.hartmanhep.net/greater2.html). To start using this, I downloaded the .m file on that page to my desktop. Then I opened a new notebook, selected "Insert", then "File Path", then selected the .m file. This seemed to load correctly. I was able to practise using the package just fine. I could use the various functions that the package has.

However, today if I open the same notebook from yesterday, I can't get the package to work. I'm getting a "Missing[UnkownSymbol, ..]" message when I try to use the functions from the package. I've also tried starting a new notebook and loading the package as I did yesterday, to no avail. I still can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Sometimes instead if the "Missing" message, I'm getting something about "Global". In case that helps identify the problem.

EDIT2: Using needs in the notebook I had yesterday leads to lots of messages like "S::shdw: Symbol S appears in multiple contexts {GREATER2`,Global`}; definitions in context GREATER2` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions." Then it looks like the packages is running, but lots of variables are now red.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please take a look at the [Needs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Needs.html) command.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I suggest you follow the installation instructions on the page of the package. Namely, put the file into one of the folders that you get with `$Path`, then use `Needs["GREATER2`"];` to load the package.

Comment: To your edits: Use `Quit` to restart the kernel, then ```Needs["GREATER2"];``` again. You should not have red symbols anymore.

Comment: Messages like  "S::shdw: Symbol S appears in multiple contexts {GREATER2,Global};" indicate that you defined "S" already in the gloobal context, e.g. by using it before loading the package.